# How to hook a process with higher integrity level?

Tags: c++, dll, process, hook, dll-injection

Is there a way we can install hooks using SetWindowsHook API to hook into the processes with higher integrity level. I need to hook into a process with 'high' integrity level from my application which runs in 'medium' integrity level.

Comment: Do you mean priority when you say integrity?  Priority a process runs at has nothing to do with your ability to hook it.

Comment: Probably not, integrity level is a different concept: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the integrity of your process. You can impersonate an admin using the systems admin profile info (if you know them) to create tokens to either retrieve the targeted process handle or give to your own process, or you can create a service to launch your process everytime the SO starts (if that's the case) because by doing so it will have enough privileges